# Is making a molex to barrel jack safe?

Tags: power-supply

I have a rockpro64 which requires a DC input of 12v at 5amp and I'm building a NAS which has a pc power supply in it. If I modify a molex so that it outputs to a barrel jack is that safe?

Comment: If the polarity, current and voltage are correct, and if you observe safe mechanical conversion practice, then it should work fine.

Comment: Of course, it depends on the wire gauge, https://kaizerpowerelectronics.dk/theory/wire-size-table/, and connector, too.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it before - and I've made mistakes. A 'good' starting point for this would be to modify a molex to fan header connector, chopping off the 'fan' header and using a screw on barrel jack.

There's a few things to think about - 5amp is a fair amount of current and you will want to check if a single 12v rail can handle it. The other thing is what the power supply does under no load. You'll also need to do some jumpering/modification of the ATX connector for the PSU to run at all. I usually 'just' stick a wire between sense and

With a 'good' PSU, a short between ground and voltage *should* cause it to shut down. Since its better to have a shut down PSU than one on fire, its worth checking on this too.

That said, depending on what *else* you're plugging in and 'how' - going pure 12v might make sense.

A different setup to consider would be a larger/appropriately sized 12v power brick, a barrel jack splitter (basically one that goes from one female barrel jack to many), and cable that goes from a male barrel jack to sata power. It would be a *lot* more compact (heck even with more than one PSU), and probably require less homebrew hardware.